# Missing ) after argument list in partials\messages.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

The following is the code for the register page and i am having a problem with the code while parsing the messages.ejs file. i am having a syntax error on <%- include('./partials/messages') %> line

Syntax error:

```
missing ) after argument list in D:\Website Practice\Nodejs\node_passport_login_project\views\partials\messages.ejs while compiling ejs
```

Can some help, please

````
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
          <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register
        </h1>
        <%- include('./partials/messages') %>
        <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input
              type="name"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter Name"
              value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            Register
          </button>
        </form>
        <p class="lead mt-4">Have An Account? <a href="/users/login">Login</a></p>
      </div>```
    </div>
  </div>
````

the code in the message file is below

```js
<% if( typeof errors != 'undefined' ){ %>
    <% errors.forEach((error){ %>
        <%= error.msg %>
    <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `function` and pass an `argument` try this hope it help!!

```
    <% if(typeof errors != 'undefined' ){ %> 
      <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
          <%= error.msg %>
        <% }); %>
     <% } %>
```